# How do I find next greater date in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with three columns:

[Employee ID] (Distinct values)
[Start Date]
[Stop Date]

I need to search a second sheet with two columns:
[Employee ID] (Non-Distinct)
[Testing date]
and return the next greater [Testing date] than each [Stop Date] on the first sheet for each employee.

I am using latest Excel 365

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I understand how to use Index and Match on a simple column of data, but can't figure out how to use it with the data I have.  (I'm not an expert by any means!)

Comment: use `Filter` and then wrap a `min` around it

Comment: Thank you for this!